# Http POST 405 errror in Angularjs with Spring MVC

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Actually I want to integrate Spring with Angularjs and i am beginner in Angularjs. When i use $http post method it return POST 405.Here is my code

**SignUp.html**

```
<form method="post" ng-submit="saveUser()">
                                <input type="hidden" name="${_csrf.parameterName}"
                                    value="${_csrf.token}" />
</form>
```

**myApp.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngMessages']);
```

**UserIdController.js**

```
myApp.controller('UserIdController', [
    '$scope',
    'UserIdService',
    function($scope, UserIdService) {
        $scope.saveUser = function() {
            UserIdService.saveUser($scope.user).then(
                    function success(response) {
                        console.log("user Added");
                    }, function error(response) {
                        console.log("User not Added")
                    });
        }
    } ]);
```

**UserIdService.js**

```
myApp
    .service(
            'UserIdService',
            [
                    '$http',
                    function($http) {
                        this.saveUser = function saveUser(user) {
                            return $http({
                                method : 'post',
                                url : 'SignUpUser',
                                data : {
                                    firstName : user.firstName
                                },
                                headers : 'Content-Type: application/json'
                            });
                        }
                    } ]);
```

**Spring REST Controller**

```
    @RestController
    @Produces("text/plain")
    public class SignUpController {

       private static final Logger logger = 
       LogManager.getLogger(SignUpController.class);

      @RequestMapping(value = "/SignUpUser", method = 
      RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
      public String saveUser(@PathVariable String firstname) throws 
        ParseException {

        logger.debug("Enter in SignUp Controller in Post Method");
        UserDetails userDetails = new UserDetails();
        studentDetails.setFirstName(firstname);
       return "ok";
     }
```

I got this error in Chrome in Inspect element

```
      Request URL:http://localhost:8080/examapp/signup
      Request Method:POST
      Status Code:405 
      Remote Address:[::1]:8080
      Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
      Response Headers
     view parsed
     HTTP/1.1 405
     Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
     Pragma: no-cache
     Expires: 0
     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
     X-Frame-Options: DENY
     X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
     Allow: GET
     Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
     Content-Language: en
     Content-Length: 1084 
     Date: Fri, 04 Aug 2017 05:50:32 GMT
     Request Headers
     view source
     Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
     Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
     Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
     Connection:keep-alive 
     Content-Length:26
     Content-Type:application/json
     Cookie:JSESSIONID=ACF3E30CB7B3A6A9862F923F42DB61B5
     Host:localhost:8080
     Origin:http://localhost:8080
     Referer:http://localhost:8080/examapp/signup.html
     User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
     (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.78 Safari/537.36
     Request Payload
```

Does anyone have an idea of what I'm doing wrong? It seems like a pretty straight forward implementation that is working on all of the tutorials I've seen yet. Any help will be appreciated. **Thank you.**

Comment: Is POST method allowed by the server for Signup API ?

Comment: did you able to hit your api with postman

Answer (score 0):

Please add  `@RequestMapping("/examapp")` over your`SignUpController`

```
@RestController
@Produces("text/plain")
@RequestMapping("/examapp")
    public class SignUpController {
```

Answer (score 0):

You have specified [@PathVariable](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/PathVariable.html) here. A path variable is just that, a variable from the path. What you want is [@RequestBody](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestBody.html).

In your scenario, Spring has nothing maped to /SignUpUser, it is looking for /SignUpUser/{firstName}, but since @RequestMapping doesn't specify {firstName}, you are essentially posting to a non-existent resource.

Although unrealistic in the real world, to post just a first name to login, In your `$http.post`, you would just want `data : user.firstName`.

In your Spring controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/SignUpUser", method = 
      RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
      public String saveUser(@RequestBody String firstname)
```

### The Right Fix

If you want your back-end to accept what you have in Angular (more real-world), you would create a POJO class, and accept that (`@RequestBody UserDetails request)`. It appears you have the UserDetails POJO created, so you just have to accept that instead:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/SignUpUser", method = 
      RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json")
      public String saveUser(@RequestBody UserDetails userDetails ) {
```

Comment: I changed my code as you tell bt error as it is .Actually i get error in Angularjs and error is xhr.send(isUndefined(post) ? null : post);

Comment: Change post -> POST.

Comment: What do you get if you run your app with --debug flag? Do you have anything in the console from Spring?

Comment: Also, can you POST from the CLI or a script (curl, powershell) for *nix, win?

Comment: I get error in console          http-nio-8080-exec-4] WARN org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - Request method 'POST' not supported and my browser show POST 405() error